# Avoid error out of range SQL during database migration

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-types

i'm stuck on a problem of migration in my SQL Tables,

example i have a table called Error that contains values

```
latitude DECIMAL(9,2)
longitude DECIMAL(10,8)
info DECIMAL(11,8)
idsf int
sf tinyint
value float
```

Theses rows have to change to :

```
latitude DECIMAL(9,2) => DECIMAL(7,1)
longitude DECIMAL(10,8) => DECIMAL(8,6)
info DECIMAL(11,8) => DECIMAL(9,6)
idsf int => DECIMAL(7,2)
sf tinyint => DECIMAL(5,2)
value float => DECIMAL(7,1)
```

The problem is i have everytime a problem with out of range because some value are not automatically truncated.

Is this possible to have a workaround ?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

You can update the data to set the values to in-range types.  This looks like:

```
update t
    set latitude = (case when latitude between -999999.9 and 999999.9
                         then latitude
                    end),
        longitude = (case when longitude between -99.999999 and 99.999999
                          then longitude
                     end),
        . . .
```

I would recommend, though, that you investigate the values first to determine what the incorrect values look like -- and hence how to handle them.

Even at this point, the data looks suspicious:

- `latitude` and `longitude` normally have the same data type.
- `longitudes` vary from -180 to 180 -- assuming they are measured in degrees.
- `latitudes` and `logitudes` would typically have 4 or 6 decimal points, so I would expect something like `decimal(9, 6)` or something like that.

No doubt, there might be other issues as well.

Comment: Thank for your answer, the thing is i don't even know what exactly is inside all latitude and longitude because of more than 3 million rows... 
I don't really understand what the Code stand for, is this to make for example convert all latitude values to something included in -999999.9 to 99999.9 ?

Comment: @xFGerald . . . No.  This replaces values outside that range with `NULL` so you won't get a conversion error.

Comment: So i will lost values ?

Comment: @xFGerald . . . The answer specifically provides a warning to this effect.  You need to figure out what to do with out-of-range values if you want to change the data type.